# Replace a DIV with multiple class with a new class on click

Tags: jquery

My HTML is as follow.

```
<div class="box w-25 h-25">
<p>test</p>
</div>
<div class="box w-30 h-30">
<p>test</p>
</div>
<div class="box w-30 h-30">
<p>test</p>
</div>
```

and my css

```
.test {
width:100%
height:100%
z-index: 999
}

.box {
....
}

.w-25{ width: 25%; }
.w-30{ width: 30%; }
.w-40{ width: 40%; }

.h-25{ height: 25%; }
.h-30{ height: 30%; }
.h-40{ height: 40%; }
```

Is it possible to replace the original class with .test when I click on them individually with jQuery as to create an overlay effect?

Comment: Which *original class*? You want to replace "box" with "test"?

Comment: Do you mean when you click then the classes 'box w-xx h-xx' should be removed from div, and just one class `test` will be set to the div .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Remove/Replace Classes

There are a few ways to remove all classes, and leave only one. You could use `$.attr`:

```
$(".box").on("click", function(){
  $(this).attr("class", "test");
});
```

This sets the full value of `class` to a single classname. Alternatively, you could set the `className` on the element itself:

```
$(".box").on("click", function(){
  this.className = "test";
});
```

Or, you could call `$.removeClass()` without any arguments (which removes all classes), and then follow that up by adding your `test` class:

```
$(".box").on("click", function(){
  $(this).removeClass().addClass("test");
});
```

#### Avoid Ambiguity

I'm assuming that you don't have any other `.box` elements on the page - if you do, the selector used here would need to be modified just a bit to affect only the boxes we wish to target.

If these boxes were within a larger container:

```
<div id="boxes">
  <div class="box w-25 h-25">...</div>
  <div class="box w-30 h-30">...</div>
</div>
```

We might change our selector to include the container `id`:

```
$("#boxes .box").on("click" function(){
  /* React */
});
```

#### Toggle On/Off

From the comments, the OP expressed a desire to *remember* the original classes, and swap `.test` out for them if the element were clicked on a second time. Below is one possible solution to this:

```
$(".box").on("click", function(){
  // Store original class attribute as data
  $(this).data("o") || $(this).data("o", $(this).attr("class"));
  // Set new class attribute to test, or to original
  $(this).attr("class", function(i,o){
    return o != $(this).data("o") ? $(this).data("o") : "test" ;
  });
});
```

Comment: But with that I will have <div class="test w-25 h-25"> .. basically what I want to achieve is change <div class="box w-25 h-25"> to <div class="test"> .. is that possible?

Comment: @ClementCkh I've updated the answer to do as you've requested.

Comment: @JonathanSampson That should work for him but what if the div have the class `box classX1 classX2` . In that case too your code will change box to test. Nevertheless, @Clement might not be facing this issue right now, but may be in future ;)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion and noticing the double-quote, that was a typo.   Your solution is exactly what I need.  Thanks!

Comment: @RakeshJuyal I'm assuming the OP doesn't have any other `.box` elements on the page that might be confused here. If so, a simple modification to the jQuery selector should suffice.

Comment: @JonathanSampson absolutely right. But could you please do that modification to show how that can be done. That will be very nice.

Comment: @RakeshJuyal I've provided that information at the bottom of the answer.

Comment: Alright I hope this is not causing an issue.  After I change it to .test, can I have the action reversed when I click again for it to return to the original state?

Comment: @ClementCkh So it needs to remember all of the classes it had to begin with?

Comment: I think that is the case.  I am basically trying to create an overlay.  I have 3 contents on the page, as I click on them they become .test (the overlay) and when I click again it returns to the original page.  I am not sure if this is the right approach to create an overlay .. I am very new at jQuery.

Comment: @ClementCkh Check the bottom of my answer for a method of toggling.

Comment: That seems to do the trick.  Tested on fiddle and it works just as I wanted it to be.  I will try it on my site now.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry it took me a long time to implement the code on my page.  Seems like the code only works on the first div on the page.  I do have three .box div on the same page and when the code executes, it always overlay the content of the first div.  If I want to overlay the content of whichever .box I click, is there a solution to this?

Comment: @ClementCkh It appears to work on multiple boxes just fine: http://jsbin.com/ajiquf/edit#javascript,html

Comment: What happen on my website is that when I clicked on one of the DIVS, all three DIVS were given the class .test .. I only want the one I clicked to inherit that class

Comment: @ClementCkh The code to toggle, at the bottom of my answer, only affects the `.box` you clicked on. You can see by visiting http://jsbin.com/ajiquf/edit#javascript,html. If all of the `.box` elements are affected, you either implemented my solution incorrectly, or you might have markup issues.

Comment: Sorry my bad.  It was indeed a typo in my .js and it's working fine after I have corrected it.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove all classes from a a div, all you would have to do is :

`$('.box').attr('class', 'test');`

this will replace the entire class attribute with whatever you want. or you can just empty out the class attribute :

`$('.box').attr('class', '');`

and then do addClass for any classes you would need programatically using:

`$('.box').addClass('test');`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".box").on("click", function(){
  $(this).removeClass(). // remove all class
         addClass("test");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This will keep on toggling the `box` class with `test`. Also, I have added the check wherein class will be changed only if div have other class i.e. w-xx and h-xx too.

@Jonathan , Please see how can we improve this one.  I have create the demo here: http://jsbin.com/ucotot/

```
$(function() {
  $('div.box').click ( function () {
    var classes = $(this).attr ('class').split(' ');

    var widthClassFound = false;
    var heightClassFound = false;
    for ( i = 0; i < classes.length; i++ ){
      if ( classes[i].match("^w-") ){
        widthClassFound = true;
    }

      if ( classes[i].match("^h-") ){
        heightClassFound = true;
    }

    }

    if ( widthClassFound && heightClassFound ) {
      if ( $(this).data('originalClass') ) {
        $(this).removeClass().addClass($(this).data('originalClass'));
        $(this).removeData('originalClass'); 
      }else{

      $(this).data ( 'originalClass', $(this).attr ('class') ); //Saving all class box, w-xx , h-xx
       $(this).removeClass('box').addClass('test');

      }

    }


  });

});
```

**Edit**

Above code toggles `box` class with `test`, as @Clement is asking to toggle all classes with `test` following code can be used. see demo: http://jsbin.com/ucotot/3

```
   $(function() {
  $('div.box, div.test').click ( function () {
    if ( $(this).data('originalClass') ) {  // if 'originalClass' is present in data then use it and return;
         $(this).removeClass().addClass($(this).data('originalClass'));
        $(this).removeData('originalClass'); 

      return;

    }


    var classes = $(this).attr ('class').split(' ');

    var widthClassFound = false;
    var heightClassFound = false;
    for ( i = 0; i < classes.length; i++ ){
      if ( classes[i].match("^w-") ){
        widthClassFound = true;
    }

      if ( classes[i].match("^h-") ){
        heightClassFound = true;
    }

    }

    if ( widthClassFound && heightClassFound ) {


      $(this).data ( 'originalClass', $(this).attr ('class') ); //Saving all class box, w-xx , h-xx
       $(this).removeClass().addClass('test');



    }


  });

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your code.  It seems like the box is replaced by test but w-xx and h-xx remains.  My intention is to replace it completely with test.  Seems like the latest solution given by @Jonathan will do the job.

Comment: I am trying to implement your approach now.  Is it possible that the class is completely changed to .test on click and change back to the original class on the second click?

Comment: @ClementCkh sure. replace ... `$(this).removeClass('box')` with `$(this).removeClass()`